# How to support navigation drawer (all features) with API 7 in android

Tags: android

How to support navigation drawer (all features) with API 7 in android & also Actionbar for api 7 or 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all Update your sdk (Extras :- Android Support Repository & Android Support Library) with latest update, then follow import appcompat (project) from following path sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat.

then add then add this android-support-v7-appcompat (Project) as a library in your Navigation drawer App. And also do some changes in your AndroidMainfest file android:minSdkVersion="7" . Now Your app can easily work with api 7 with all navigation drawer features.

Answer (score 2):

Actually SherlockActionBar(http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is Third party Api so its better for you to choose Android Navigation Drawer at the place of SherlockActionBar,b'coz if for further android version SherlockActionBar doesn't support so it will create lots of problem for you ,Still SharelockActionbar give supprt with api 4.2.2.

Best of Luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionBarSherlock or appcompat to accomplish this. The novigation drawer DrawerLayout works on 2.1 and ActionBarSherlock or appcompat will give you the actionbar for api 7.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html
http://actionbarsherlock.com/

and if you want to use the appcompat lib from google then you need to use the ActionBarActivity

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html